# std::atomic<bool> modified in main thread, but unchanged in other threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdatomic

I am trying to use a std::atomic to cooperatively halt some threads in my chess AI. I can't figure out why my threads continue to run when I call StopPondering(). If I break in StopPondering I see Searching get set correctly, but if I break in either of the two threads, its value is still true.
 I'm using VS 2013 on Windows 8.1
The relevant subset of the code is below.

AI0.h

```
#pragma once
#include "AI.h"
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>

class AI0 : public AI
{
public:
    virtual void Ponder(Game game, U8 depth = 0) override;
    virtual void StopPondering() override;
private:

    std::thread* SearchThread;
    std::thread* InfoThread;

    std::atomic<bool> Searching;

    void search(GameState state);
    void SendInfo();
}
```

AI0.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "AI0.h"
#include "InterfaceLayer.h"
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>

AI0::AI0()
{
    Searching = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(false);
    SearchThread = nullptr;
    InfoThread = nullptr;
}
void AI0::Ponder(Game game, U8 depth)
{
    SearchThread = new std::thread(&AI0::search, this, game.GetState());
    InfoThread = new std::thread(&AI0::SendInfo, this);
    SearchThread->detach();
    InfoThread->detach();
}

void AI0::StopPondering()
{
    Searching.store(false);
}

void AI0::search(GameState state)
{
    while (Searching.load())
    {
        //Search code.
        //Sets some global data which I do see correctly on main thread.
    }
}

void AI0::SendInfo()
{
    while (Searching.load())
    {
        //Code to update interface layer about search progress.
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}
```

I apologize for my inconsistent capitalization.

---------EDIT---------

Problem solved. I was foolishly creating multiple instances of AI0, and, as some indeed suspected, I was not calling StopPondering() on the same instance that had spawned the threads, and this was certianly a memory leak. I now only have one AI0 singleton and everything works as expected. Sorry for the fail.

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us, including how you use this `AIO` class? You do create an `AIO` object somewhere, and call `Ponder` and `StopPondering` on it? Is the lifetime of the `AIO` object longer than the lifetime of the threads?

Comment: If you create an `AI0` object for each thread, they will all have a separate `Searching` member. Unless you declare it `static`.

Comment: Also, if you call `Ponder` on an `AIO` object, and then destroy the `AIO` object besides having undefined behavior as the threads continue to run while the object doesn't exist, you will also have memory leaks as the `std::thread` objects you allocate will be lost.

Comment: @BoPersson But he is passing `this` to the threads...

Comment: To prevent the problem described by JoachimPileborg, you should call StopPondering() in the destructor and wait for the threads to finish.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Upon going to post code showing the lifecycle of AI0 I realized I was instantiating it inside a loop. Major facepalm. I moved it out of the loop and everything works as expected.

Comment: Be aware that you still have a memory leak: each time you call Ponder, new thread instances are created, but you never delete them.

Comment: @ironclownfish and this is one of the reasons why you must always post a mcve. Not only does it make it possible for us to solve your problem, but the creation of mcve is itself one of the more effective methods of debugging.

Comment: @ironclownfish Fine that you found the solution yourself. You might want to write your own answer (and accept it) so that this question does not appear as 'unanswered' any more...

Comment: Voting to close because the OP found the bug, in the never-disclosed code.